# Weak continuity under Laplace transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, laplace-transform

Let the sequence $u_n\in L^2(0,\infty)$ weakly converges to $u\in L^2(0,\infty)$. What can we say about the corresponding Laplace transforms $U_n(s)$ and $U(s)$?

1. $U_n(s)$ converges point-wise to $U(s)$ for almost all $s>0$.
2. The convergence in (1) but also uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in the question for Laplace transform should be improved for clarity.

1. The Laplace transforms $L(u_n)(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}u_n(x)\, dx$ converge to $L(u)(s)$ pointwise for each $s>0$ by the definition of weak convergence.
2. The convergence need not be uniform. E.g. take $u(x)=x/(1+x^2) \in L^2(0,\infty)$
   and $u_n(x)=u(x)$ for $x \in (0,n)$, with $u_n(x)=0$ for $x \ge n$.
   Then $u_n \to u $ in $L^2(0,\infty)$, yet $\sup_{s>0} [L(u)-L(u_n)](s)=\int_n^\infty u(x) \, dx=\infty$.

Comment: Is the converse also true? That is, if $L(u_n)(s)$ converges pointwise to $L(u)(s)$, then $u_n(t)$ converges weakly to $u(t)$?

Comment: If the above answered your question, you can indicate that by accepting the answer. https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3724/how-to-accept-answer

Comment: The comments are not really designed for asking additional questions. Without further assumptions the converse does not hold, consider $u_n(x)=n/x$ for $x>n$ and $u_n(x)=0$ elsewhere. Then $L(u_n)$ tends to $L(0)=0$ pointwise for $s>0$, but $\int_0^\infty u_n u_1\, dx=1$ for all $n$.